# HIbernate autoincrement not working

Tags: hibernate, class, pojo

If I'm using hibernate Pojo class using annotations as below - as I'm using `GenerationType.AUTO`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
```

Is there any need to add "auto-increment" in database side also for an entity...?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,You need to add in database also

Example:

```
 SQL>field_name dataType NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply. I mean if i dont want to add auto increment explicitly in Database side then how it can be possible with hibernate in Pojo with annotations..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use other generator types for that like table or sequence generators. You will not have to "auto-increment" in the column. But there will be a change in the Pojo class and you will have to create sequence in your DB.

Please refer below link for different types of generator-
[HIbernate id generators](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-identity-sequence)